# C# .wav file data analysis & draw Freq.Domain graph from it

Tags: c#

my first question in stackoverflow...so pls inform me, if i violate the forum rules

i try to analyze the audio .wav data (basically a sinusoid with/without Noise) in FFT & draw the result as a Freq. Domain graph using C#. I need to analyze the sine wave & find whether any noise is present or not for 10 to 20seconds audio data.

Sine wave was generated using Audacity with the following properties.

- 1KHz Sine Tone .wav data for 15 to 20s.
- 16Bits per sample
- 44100Hz
- Mono Channel

Here is the code part to separate the Audio data from the Header data.

```
        // --- Open & Read .wav File from the Path
        System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(waveFilePath);
        System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(WaveFile);


        // Convert the length of the file into Byte value.
        waveLength = WaveFile.Length;
        wave = new byte[waveLength];

        // --- Subtract the .wav File Header Info (First 44 Bytes) to get the real Audio Data.  Source -> http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html 
        wavenew = new byte[(waveLength - 44)];
        for (long i = 0; i < waveLength; i++)
        {
            wave[i] = br.ReadByte();
            //Get only the Audio Data byte values
            if (i >= 44)
            {
                wavenew[i - 44] = wave[i];
            }
        }

        // Bits per Sample(whether 8 Bit or 16 Bit.)- Header Information35, 36 is for Bits per Sample. 
        bitsPerSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, 34); //16Bit

        //Number of Channels - Header Information 23, 24 is for No of Channels.  (Mono or Stereo)
        noOfChannels = BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, 22); //Mono


        // Calculate the over all Audio Data length, here for FFT only values of exponential 2 can be given. So take 2 power 17 = 131072 for this calculation. Remaining Bytes will be neglected. 
        // Divide by 4 since every audio data contains 4 bytes. (Mono,16 Bit or Stereo,8 bit - 4 Bytes. Mono, 8 bit - 2 Bytes)
        dataLength = (131116-44)/4;  // /4;
        data = new double[dataLength]; 

        //SampleRate - Header Information 25 to 28 (4 Bytes) are for SampleRates
        SampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(wave, 24);     // 44100;

        // The every 4 Bytes contain the data of Sinus wave. 
        for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
        {
            data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(wavenew, (1 + i) * 4);
        }
```

Here are example raw Audio data after conversion.

890381306
1403864333
1804165263
2058843210
2147319456
2063433407
1812231337
1414947118
903955929
320087260
-289603352
-875963166
-1391936590
-1795514361
-2054321130
-2147384959

For FFT,  I use  http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/LomontFFT.html as a reference, which returns a Double -Real & Imag Value.

```
    public void RealFFT(double[] data, bool forward)                                                         
    {                                                                                                        

        var n = data.Length; // # of real inputs, 1/2 the complex length                                     
        // checks n is a power of 2 in 2's complement format                                                 
        if ((n & (n - 1)) != 0)                                                                              
            throw new ArgumentException(                                                                     
                "data length " + n + " in FFT is not a power of 2"                                           
                );                                                                                           

        var sign = -1.0; // assume inverse FFT, this controls how algebra below works                        
        if (forward)                                                                                         
        { // do packed FFT. This can be changed to FFT to save memory                                        
            TableFFT(data, true);                                                                            
            sign = 1.0;                                                                                      
            // scaling - divide by scaling for N/2, then mult by scaling for N                               
            if (A != 1)                                                                                      
            {                                                                                                
                var scale = Math.Pow(2.0, (A - 1) / 2.0);                                                    
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)                                                        
                    data[i] *= scale;                                                                        
            }                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                    

        var theta = B * sign * 2 * Math.PI / n;                                                              
        var wpr = Math.Cos(theta);                                                                           
        var wpi = Math.Sin(theta);                                                                           
        var wjr = wpr;                                                                                       
        var wji = wpi;                                                                                       

        for (var j = 1; j <= n/4; ++j)                                                                       
        {                                                                                                    
            var k = n / 2 - j;                                                                               
            var tkr = data[2 * k];    // real and imaginary parts of t_k  = t_(n/2 - j)                      
            var tki = data[2 * k + 1];                                                                       
            var tjr = data[2 * j];    // real and imaginary parts of t_j                                     
            var tji = data[2 * j + 1];                                                                       

            var a = (tjr - tkr) * wji;                                                                       
            var b = (tji + tki) * wjr;                                                                       
            var c = (tjr - tkr) * wjr;                                                                       
            var d = (tji + tki) * wji;                                                                       
            var e = (tjr + tkr);                                                                             
            var f = (tji - tki);                                                                             

            // compute entry y[j]                                                                            
            data[2 * j] = 0.5 * (e + sign * (a + b));                                                        
            data[2 * j + 1] = 0.5 * (f + sign * (d - c));                                                    

            // compute entry y[k]                                                                            
            data[2 * k] = 0.5 * (e - sign * (b + a));                                                        
            data[2 * k + 1] = 0.5 * (sign * (d - c) - f);                                                    

            var temp = wjr;                                                                                  
            // todo - allow more accurate version here? make option?                                         
            wjr = wjr * wpr - wji * wpi;                                                                     
            wji = temp * wpi + wji * wpr;                                                                    
        }                                                                                                    

        if (forward)                                                                                         
        {                                                                                                    
            // compute final y0 and y_{N/2}, store in data[0], data[1]                                       
            var temp = data[0];                                                                              
            data[0] += data[1];                                                                              
            data[1] = temp - data[1];                                                                        
        }                                                                                                    
        else                                                                                                 
        {                                                                                                    
            var temp = data[0]; // unpack the y0 and y_{N/2}, then invert FFT                                
            data[0] = 0.5 * (temp + data[1]);                                                                
            data[1] = 0.5 * (temp - data[1]);                                                                
            // do packed inverse (table based) FFT. This can be changed to regular inverse FFT to save memory
            TableFFT(data, false);                                                                           
            // scaling - divide by scaling for N, then mult by scaling for N/2                               
            //if (A != -1) // todo - off by factor of 2? this works, but something seems weird               
            {                                                                                                
                var scale = Math.Pow(2.0, -(A + 1) / 2.0)*2;                                                 
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)                                                        
                    data[i] *= scale;                                                                        
            }                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                void Scale(double[] data, int n, bool forward)                                                           
    {                                                                                                        
        // forward scaling if needed                                                                         
        if ((forward) && (A != 1))                                                                           
        {                                                                                                    
            var scale = Math.Pow(n, (A - 1) / 2.0);                                                          
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)                                                            
                data[i] *= scale;                                                                            
        }                                                                                                    

        // inverse scaling if needed                                                                         
        if ((!forward) && (A != -1))                                                                         
        {                                                                                                    
            var scale = Math.Pow(n, -(A + 1) / 2.0);                                                         
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)                                                            
                data[i] *= scale;                                                                            
        }                                                                                                    
    }    

    public void TableFFT(double[] data, bool forward)                                                        
    {                                                                                                        
        var n = data.Length;                                                                                 
        // checks n is a power of 2 in 2's complement format                                                 
        if ((n & (n - 1)) != 0)                                                                              
            throw new ArgumentException(                                                                     
                "data length " + n + " in FFT is not a power of 2"                                           
                );                                                                                           
        n /= 2;    // n is the number of samples                                                             

        Reverse(data, n); // bit index data reversal                                                         

        // make table if needed                                                                              
        if ((cosTable == null) || (cosTable.Length != n))                                                    
            Initialize(n);                                                                                   

        // do transform: so single point transforms, then doubles, etc.                                      
        double sign = forward ? B : -B;                                                                      
        var mmax = 1;                                                                                        
        var tptr = 0;                                                                                        
        while (n > mmax)                                                                                     
        {                                                                                                    
            var istep = 2 * mmax;                                                                            
            for (var m = 0; m < istep; m += 2)                                                               
            {                                                                                                
                var wr = cosTable[tptr];                                                                     
                var wi = sign * sinTable[tptr++];                                                            
                for (var k = m; k < 2 * n; k += 2 * istep)                                                   
                {                                                                                            
                    var j = k + istep;                                                                       
                    var tempr = wr * data[j] - wi * data[j + 1];                                             
                    var tempi = wi * data[j] + wr * data[j + 1];                                             
                    data[j] = data[k] - tempr;                                                               
                    data[j + 1] = data[k + 1] - tempi;                                                       
                    data[k] = data[k] + tempr;                                                               
                    data[k + 1] = data[k + 1] + tempi;                                                       
                }                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                
            mmax = istep;                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                    


        // perform data scaling as needed                                                                    
        Scale(data, n, forward);                                                                             
    }
```

Amplitude is derived from the received Real & Imag. value as below

```
     //Converting RealFFT return value in to an amplitude for Graph     
     (SqurRoot of Real*Real + Imag * Imag)
            realPart = new double[(dataLength / 2)];
            imagPart = new double[(dataLength / 2)];
            dataNew = new double[(dataLength / 2)];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataNew.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0) //Ignore the first two values, since it contain the special values. Then calculate the magnitude for real & imaginary part. 
                {           
                }
                else
                {
                    realPart[i] = data[(i * 2)] * data[(i * 2)];
                    imagPart[i] = data[((i * 2) + 1)] * data[((i * 2) + 1)];
                    dataNew[i] = Math.Sqrt(realPart[i] + imagPart[i]);
                }
            }
            // Get these values for Y Axis as Amplitude
            Values.Add(dataNew);
            int N = dataNew.Length;

            double[] frequencies = new double[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            {
                if (i < (N / 2))
                {
                    frequencies[i] = i * SampleRate / N;
                }
                else if (i >= (N / 2))
                {
                    frequencies[i] = (N - i) * SampleRate / N;
                }

                //frequencies[i] = (i / N); //*10;

            }

            // Get the Frequency values for X Axis
            Values.Add(frequencies);
```

Processed Amplitude values are looking like..

0
9030724,08220743
78204971,4566076
11562334,8871099
10855402,9273669
9213306,99124749
39816810,42806
9154491,10446211
10747893,2800474
9744695,14696198
140738122,900694

Derived Frequency from the sample rate are as follows

0
2
5
8
10
13
16
18
21
24
26
29

Finally the graph does not show the correct Freq range & peaks are observed through out the  chart, even though the .wav file is a pure sine wave & does not contain any noise.  (I´m not able to attach the graph image due to missing reputation, but i´m ready to post it.)

As per Sinus Tone, there should be only one peak around 1KHz, but I´m seeing again sinus like signal.   I´ve checked with the different frequencies, but the result does not match with the expectation.

I could not clearly figure out where I´m doing the mistake, whether

- Processing Audio Data (Splitting 4 Bytes after Header Info to Double)
- Processing data within FFT
- or Amplitude/Freq Graph calculation.

I´m ready to provide additional information, if required & any help would be appreciated.